# How to send out 60khz signal from antenna?

Tags: transistors, raspberry-pi, antenna, radio, npn

**BACKGROUND**

In Japan there are radio-controlled clocks. Time is synchronized by 40khz (in west Japan) and 60khz (in east Japan) radio, which is broadcast from transmission towers. The signal is known as JJY:

https:/ /en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JJY

After the earthquake in 2011, the tower in the east Japan was collapsed. Time synchronization in the east Japan is affected. Hence, someone Japanese has made a simulators and shared on the Internet.

---

I am from Hong Kong. I have a radio-controlled watch and clock bought from Japan. I want my devices to be synchronized. There are iOS and Android app JJY-simulators. I have tried some of them. This one works well:

https:/ /play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.houryo.jjyemulator&hl=ja

The principle behind is, using time from NTP server, emulating the JJY signal, sending out through 3.5mm audio port.

[image]

---

Now I want to implement the emulator on a Raspberry-Pi. There are some tutorials found on the Internet. Below is the one I am following to:

http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/atcl/column/14/093000080/093000002/?ST=oss&P=1 (Japanese)

Instead of the source-code in the tutorial, I use this one:
https://github.com/snt/rpi_jjy_server

---

**PROBLEM**

I have made the circuit following the tutorial:
[image]

[image]

However, most of the time my watch does not read any signal.
If there is signal, the signal status is "low", and eventually the time-sync is failed. (For the Android-app one, my watch can read a "high" signal.)

Note: I am using Toshiba 2SC1815-GR transistor, 30k ohm resistors, which are suggested in the Git-hub article. And a telephone-line made antenna.

[image]

I have tried using a 9V battery replacing the 5V Raspberry-Pi power source. But it does not help.

My knowledge on electronic is very limited. Please kindly forgive me if I have asked silly questions or made silly mistakes. Could anyone please point out if I am made anything wrongly? Or, by what means could I boost the signal from the antenna?

**Great appreciation for any help!**

Comment: Personally I would just reverse-engineer the antenna for the smartphone. use an oscilloscope to check the signal and try to reproduce it. But my first thought is.. The antenna look quite different. Did you try to attach the 3.5mm antenna to the ciruit to see if it works?

Comment: The 3.5mm antenna is the same with the one I am using on the Raspberry-Pi. They are the twisted-wires inside one telephone line. And I did try using the 3.5mm one on the Raspberry. It does not work. (Actually does the antenna really work with only one end connected onto the breadboard?)

An oscilloscope is too expensive for me, as I am just a beginner working on this just for fun.

Comment: Yes, the wire is the same, but the size matters too. And... usually electrically-coupled antennas have just one wire attached, but magnetically-coupled ones have both of them attached. Did the second website describe the antenna? Because I think you need just a plece of wire, not a coil...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have no idea on "electrically-coupled" and "magnetically-coupled" antennas. Let me have some research for understanding first!

Comment: At these low frequencies I think a magnetic loop antenna works better, see my answer.

Comment: The article said:
Find a vinyl line with 1x-cm to several meters, make a loop, place it near to a radio-controlled clock; Place one end onto the breadboard.

最も簡単なのはGPIOでLEDを点灯する回路を作り、LEDとトランジスタのコレクタの間からビニール線（数十センチから数メートル程度）を引き出して、その線をぐるぐる巻きにしておくというものでしょう。その「アンテナ」を電波時計の近くに置きます。ぐるぐる巻きにしたビニール線は、テープで輪が解けないように止めておきます（写真5）。ビニール線の一端をむき、ブレッドボードの穴に刺さる程度の太さに芯線をまとめてください。銅単線を使うともっと楽かもしれません。

So I believe the original set-up should work?

Comment: Look at the photo, the loop is connected to the smartphone's audio output with 2 connections !

Comment: Yes. And that's why I am posting the photo as well. I believe they (the antennas) behave in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Actually does the antenna really work with only one end connected onto the breadboard?" No, not this type of antenna. What you have is a loop antenna and it creates a magnetic field. You're now using it as if it is an electrical antenna and that would work IF it was very long, for 60 kHz we're talking 1250 meters (!!!) and not rolled up like yours.

I suggest you connect the open end of the antenna to +5 V BUT to limit the current, use a series resistor of value 1 kohm or so.

If you build this then I think there's a good chance it will work.
Note how the Antenna is a coil (long wire with many turns) and both ends of the wire are connected !

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ6wci.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry but my knowledge is limited. Is the physical shape of the antenna, or the way of connection decides the form (electrical / magnetic) of the antenna?

Comment: Antennas, that is a difficult subject ! Antennas emit EM waves so both electric and magnetic. However for some types the magnetic field is stronger, for others the electric field. That might also be related to how you connect it. Usually one-side connected antennas are electrical and two-sided with a conductive connection (like yours) are magnetic.

Comment: So, since I am connecting one pin only, making the antenna work as an electrical one, limiting the current with 1k ohm resistor would make the signal "better" without making the length of the antenna longer, right?

Comment: How about if I want to make the antenna into a magnetic one, do I need to modify the hardware, or the code?

Comment: The 1 kohm resistor is needed to limit the current as your antenna loop is essentially just a long wire. Just do as I suggested, connect the open end of the antenna to +5V through the 1 kohm resistor, that is all you need to do. You are using a loop antenna, it is supposed to work as a magnetic antenna. There is no need to change your code.

Comment: I have just tried the circuit you have given me. Although it looks promising, my watch can still read no signal. Do you have any idea?
http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a298/y2kbugleung/2015-12-03%2012.15.38_zpsqyxt1rnw.jpg

Comment: Your circuit now looks OK to me. Are you sure a GPIO output can provide the correct signal ? I'm saying this since the original project uses the audio output of a phone, which is an analog output. Maybe it just takes a lot of time for the watch to receive the time signal. Are you sure it is in receiving mode ? Normally these watches receive the time only once a day to save battery.

Comment: My watch used to receive "low" signal from GPIO, and there is tutorial on using GPIO as signal output, I think it is possible. (Yet, I cannot confirm there is any signal from GPIO as there is no way for me to check) I am can put my watch into force-sync mode. The "second-pin" of the watch would point to 12 when start sync-ing mode, and pointing to "H", "L" for high and low signal, amd "N" for no signal. And I have a clock for test as well.  The same result.

Comment: Sorry for the title. The project is generating 40khz signal but not 60khz.

I have read an article before doing this project. http://a-chien.blogspot.hk/2013/08/blog-post_2620.html (Chinese) It seems that computer cannot generate 40khz signal. We are making the harmony of 13.3khz signal, and hence 40khz. (I am not sure what I am saying :P) May you understand by reading the graphs in the article? I am not sure if this can help on this issue. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: From an audio port you usually cannot make 40 kHz indeed as audio goes up to 20 kHz. I understand about the 3rd harmonic of 13.3333 kHz, that is indeed 40 kHz. But with the GPIO port you might be able to make 40 kHz directly. Problem is we don't know if the signal you make is any good for the watch, maybe it is too strong ? Normally these signals are very weak. Interesting project though, if only you could get it to work :-)

Comment: Ah I see. I will keep figuring out the solution. My friend studying in university may help lending an oscilloscope to me. I will keep here updated. Thanks for your great help again!

Comment: Yes an oscilloscope will help a lot ! Good luck with your project.

Comment: Excuse me, I would like to ask on some basic ideas. How do you determine what resistors to use in the circuit? And, is there any relationship between the voltage input into base pin of the transistor, and the output from the emitter? Thanks.

Comment: Yes there is but that cannot be explained in a few lines ! This is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor  The resistor values are not so critical in your circuit ( 2x larger or smaller would also work), I just used values as what I normally use and 9 out of 10 times that is good enough. I've been playing with transistors for 30 years so I don't need to think about it so much anymore.

Comment: Wow 30 years! :o Some updates. I have switched to use the C source code from the Japanese tutorial, instead of the Python code. It uses the bcm2835 chip on the Raspberry-Pi to generate accurate "gap" between pulses. After some trials, my watch can constantly read "low" signal, and sometimes "high" signal. But it seems the time sync could not be completed yet. I think I need to make the signal better. May I know, should I make more loops, use a longer wire, or higher voltage so as to produce a stronger signal? What's the diff between a line and a loop antenna? How about adding aluminium foil?

Comment: 30 years because I started early in life :-) Since your watch now seems to have low/hi signal I think the antenna etc is OK. I would concentrate on the timing signal and check that it is what it should be. Maybe use the oscilloscope to be sure. I do not expect changing antenna, adding tin foil etc will improve anything.

Comment: I am figuring out if the "Real Time performance constraints" help: http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/ I love science very much since I was a child. Since students in Hong Kong are put into "arts"and "science" streams in study, and I went to "arts" stream with friends, I cannot keep up my interest with my knowledge. HK is a business society... Raspberry-Pi is really a good "toy" for me to pick up everything at this age :D

Comment: It seems I have got it working: http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a298/y2kbugleung/2015-12-04%2019.03.53_zpsumbjixvu.jpg But I still need to enhance the signal, as I want it to be received within 1 - 2 meters. May you please teach me how to do so? http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a298/y2kbugleung/2015-12-04%2019.04.24_zpsb3gyfmvh.jpg

Comment: By the way I have found something strange. This is the C program I am using: http://pastebin.com/QLSSv0rz It should emitting 40khz signal. In Japan, 40khz is used in the East and 60khz is used in the West. But as you could see in the picture I have posted in the last message, the clock shown "W" instead of "E". Is there any means the signal the antenna emitting be affected and changed into 60khz?

Comment: The 40 kHz has nothing to do with the antenna ! The antenna is just a piece of wire. The 40 or 60 kHz is defined in the code by the RPi. It was difficult to find but I think I found it, look in: void gen_pulse(int ms), and more specifically: bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(12); there are 2 of those, 2 x 12 us = 24 us and 1/24us = 41.67 kHz, OK not 40 kHz but close enough. Perhaps the official time transmitter is also at 41.67 kHz. So for 60 kHz: 1/ 60 kHz = 16.67 us /2 = 8.33 us. So if you change bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(12) to bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(8.333) you should get 60 kHz

Comment: But check what frequency the official transmitter actually uses, as it could also be that you need bcm2835_delayMicroseconds(8) so that would be 2 x 8 us = 16 us: 1/ 16 us = 62.5 kHz.

Comment: If you want to extend the range of your transmitter you could lower the 1 kohm resistor in series with the antenna to 470 ohms or even better, make a larger loop antenna. But you will need a lot of wire for that, I'm thinking 50 cm wide antenna and 10 loops or so. So 5 m wire at least.

Comment: I believe theoretically it should be 40khz and 60khz http://jjy.nict.go.jp/jjy/trans/index-e.html My point is, the RPi should sending out 40khz signal, but the clock reads 60khz. It is strange. Do you mean 50cm in diameter for the antenna? Is there any article I can read about the relationship between voltage, diameter, number of loops, thickness of wire, shape of the antenna, etc., towards the signal strength of the antenna? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I mean 50 cm diameter for the antenna but that is just my guess ! There are books about antenna's, loads of them actually. But, don't read those unless you want to become an antenna expert. Antenna's is a complicated subject. I think in your case the best is just to experiment a bit.

Comment: I have tried making 28cm diameter and15 loop as the antenna. This size is around the maximum limit for me to place at home. (HK is scare of place) Tried to swap the resistor values, the signal length seems do not help much. Given that I want to keep around 30cm as diameter, could I simply add more loops to increase the signal length? Still the strange thing, my clock is still showing "W" (receiving 60khz signal) while I am sending out 40khz in code. Changing into 8.3ms in code (sending out 60khz), my clock receives very weak or no signal. It seems the signal sending out is problematic?

Comment: And, as I found on the Internet, the signal should be sent from the two side of the antenna, instead of the "hole". So, this placement should be correct, right?
http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a298/y2kbugleung/2015-12-08%2019.26.13_zpsx35qdmgk.jpg

Comment: You have a cool setup there :-) Excellent ! Yes the signal will come out of the front and back of the antenna so that placement should be OK. Also since the frequency is very low placement is not so critical. If I were you I would experiment with the 8.3 ms in the  code, make it larger and smaller, see what works best. Also a trick is to see what works, for example: if 7.5 ms - 8.5 ms works, make it 8.0 ms which is right in the middle.

Comment: I have just read the tutorial carefully again. (I am not fluent in Japanese, so I just skimmed through the paragraphs). ただし、安定した発振ではありません。パルス幅には若干のゆらぎ（ジッターと言います）が生じます。その原因は、LinuxがマルチタスクOSだからです。マルチタスクOSでは、動作中に様々な割り込みに応答しなければなりませんし、OS自体を動作させるために定期的なタイマー割り込みが発生しています。It says as Linux is a multitasking OS, the script won't be handled solely with all CPU time. So the signal could not be pure 40khz, as 12ms sleep could not be achieved. @FakeMoustache do you familiar with C? I have seen "Real Time performance constraints" but have no idea how to apply it. I believe this should be the key point. Thanks

Comment: NVM, I think it is running as "real-time" priority already:
1479 root      rt   0   18192   1464   1136 R  60.5  0.2   0:22.13 waveclock

Comment: No I'm not familiar with C, I use Python mainly which is much easier :-) I would also try to give the program a high priority. There is only so much you can do in a multitasking environment like Linux. But also, for a fast CPU a millisecond is a long time.

Comment: yeah it is strange.
wait for next second, 697634 usec
wait for next minute, 13000000 usec
Current time: 2015/12/09 13:54:00
Current time: 2015/12/09 13:54:59
Current time: 2015/12/09 13:55:59
...
Current time: 2015/12/09 15:17:37
Current time: 2015/12/09 15:18:37
Current time: 2015/12/09 15:19:36
As far as I understand, the sending progress should last for 1-minute, and immediately start another sending progress.

Comment: Oh? Isn't a millisecond a "standard"? Would it be faster on some CPU and slower on others? :o

Comment: Yes of course a millisecond is a millisecond BUT Linux is not a real time OS so it cannot guarantee that it will wait 1 ms when you tell it to wait 1 ms. Linux will do its best but it can be a bit longer than 1 ms when the CPU is busy. Time critical systems use real-time OSes but these generally do not multitask so then timing can be almost guaranteed.

Comment: Okay let me update the status. After last comment, I went to study real-time Raspbian. After many times of trials, the BCM2835 code still does not work. But luckily being pointed out by a Taiwanese http://gnitnawtw.blogspot.hk/2015/10/piquadcopter-raspberry-pi.html , I believe it is pointless to try BCM2835 anymore. As stated in the webpage http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/ changelog 1.9, it costs 100-200us to call the delay function. While I just need my script to delay 12us each time. I think it explains why the signal is not accurate, and looks like 60khz rather than 40khz.

Comment: And as suggested by the Taiwanese author, I am going to try this instead: http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/

Comment: I am interested if this one would be used as if an antenna: http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf05tech.htm

Comment: No, that's something completely different ! It's an ultrasonic (high frequency sound) distance sensor. Maybe you got confused by the radiation pattern which looks like it could be from an antenna. It is a similar graph indeed but it shows sound output, not electromagnetic wave power.

Comment: After last update, I have searched on the Internet and tried different ways to achieve 12us on Raspberry. However, with an OS, it seems impossible to do so. And I have started playing with my new Arduino. Today I have just got the Internet module, after some program modification, it works finally! Hurray! The clock can receive "high" signal. But it is still strange that the Arduino emits 40khz singal, and the clock says it is receiving 60khz. I still need to make the antenna smaller and longer in reception range. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For someone's interest in the future, this is the webpage contains Arduino program:
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/NeoCat/20110328/1301256560

Comment: And the program needs to be updated before it could run. Please search the original link in this page to find the article.
Please skip step 6, as it will fail the program.

http://seesaawiki.jp/system3333/d/ArduinoIDE(%A5%C8%A5%E9%A5%D6%A5%EB%A5%B7%A5%E5%A1%BC%A5%C6%A5%A3%A5%F3%A5%B0)